# Magento: How to set up cron?

Tags: magento, cron

The very first thing, I know that there are already many solutions available and this question has been asked many time. But none of them helped me set up my cron.

1. First thing I did to get my root directory is, I created a php file and put this code in it:

   echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
2. Uploaded that file to root directory where my file cron.php is located.
3. Accessed that file in browser and copy the value of my root directory.

   /home2/rockr/public_html
4. Selected every 5 minutes from "Common settings" of cron tab of server.
5. Enter in this command:

   /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/home2/rockr/public_html/cron.php

Below is image of my cron tab, adding new cron job page:

That's it.

Still my cron job is not working. How can I figure out the problem or is there any problem with the above steps?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out myself, problem was that I was adding `/var/www/vhosts` for no reason. When the value for my root directory didn't include this value so there was no reason to put it in there.

So instead of this:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/home2/rockr/public_html/cron.php
```

Correct command was:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home2/rockr/public_html/cron.php
```

Hope this will help someone like me :)